# .htaccess old domain to a new domain not working when structure page IS NOT the same

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this on my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.houstonhouseandhome.net/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.houseandhomeonline\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.houstonhouseandhome.net/ [R=301,L]
```

The homepage goes to the new domain, but the subpages of the old domain are not going to the index of the new domain. they go to the new domain and look for the very same page, is there a way that the requests from the old domain pages go to the new domain index?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you've got two sets of rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.houstonhouseandhome.net/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

And then

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.houseandhomeonline\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.houstonhouseandhome.net/ [R=301,L]
```

You only need the first set.  The `[L]` flag tells apache to stop processing any more rules if this one matches.  Since it will match everything, the second set of rules will never take effect.

To to stop everything trying to find a relative page on the new domain, you simply remove the `$1` from the end of the domain.  So your htaccess file will look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.houstonhouseandhome.net/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note**

Since you're using 301 redirects, make sure your browser has cleared its cache/history before retesting.  Browsers will not request an url it thinks will respond with a 301.